# mod_fcgid: stderr: Problem with the SSL CA cert (path? access rights?)

Tags: webmin, centos, openssl

Some days ago I started to get these errors from my Wordpress website.

> [Sat Jan 31 07:51:34 2015] [warn] [client server's IP] mod_fcgid:
> stderr: Problem with the SSL CA cert (path? access rights?)

This is a Centos 6 system managed by Webmin/Virtualmin

> yum -y update

gave me an error:

> error: rpmts_HdrFromFdno: Header V3 RSA/SHA1 Signature, key ID c105b9de: BAD
>
> Problem opening package openssl-1.0.1e-30.el6_6.5.x86_64.rpm

[This page](https://techjourney.net/centos-yum-rpm-error-rpmts_hdrfromfdno-rpmdbnextiterator-header-v3-rsasha1-signature-key-id-bad/) contains the solution:

> yumdownloader nss-softokn-freebl
>
> rpm2cpio nss-softokn-freebl-3.14.3-22.el6_6.x86_64.rpm | cpio -idmv
>
> cp ./lib64/libfreeblpriv3.* /lib64
>
> yum -y update

Got to Virtualmin Packages to verify all is up-to-date

Comment: I'm not clear what your problem is.   You to say at the end that everything is fine now.

Comment: I had marked "Answer your own question".  It was an openssl update problem: updater could not read its Version 3 Signature

Comment: In the future, when you answer your own question, put the answer in the answer box rather than in the box with the question.